# Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't boot after moving to different partitions

Tags: 14.04, boot, partitioning

My original setup:

SSD:

```
/dev/sdc1: Windows System Reserve
/dev/sdc2: Windows
/dev/sdc3: /root
```

HDD1:

```
/dev/sda1: NTFS Storage
```

HDD2:

```
/dev/sdb2: Windows Documents
/dev/sdb1: Extended
  /dev/sdb5: /usr/local
  /dev/sdb6: /home
```

HDD2 is only 320GB, and I quickly ran out of room for my `/home` partition.  So I decided to move both `/usr/local` and `/home` to HDD1, since it is a 1TB hard drive.  So the changes result in:

SSD:

```
/dev/sdc1: Windows System Reserve
/dev/sdc2: Windows
/dev/sdc3: /root
```

HDD1:

```
/dev/sda1: NTFS Storage
/dev/sda2: Extended
  /dev/sda5: /usr/local
  /dev/sda6: /home
```

HDD2:

```
/dev/sdb2: Windows Documents
/dev/sdb1: Extended
  /dev/sdb5: old /usr/local
  /dev/sdb6: old /home
```

I left the original `/usr/local` and `/home` partitions on HDD2 just in case something went wrong during the copy over to HDD1.  I also updated my `/etc/fstab` folder to reflect the changes to `/home` and `/usr/local`.

`sudo blkid`:

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs" 
/dev/sr1: LABEL="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" 
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Storage" UUID="D83C84BC3C8496E2" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="9017071b-73f2-48af-b205-c1231139a414" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="fc258128-7f32-4bbb-8b14-9c3d3da05619" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="Windows Documents" UUID="024A89D14A89C1C1" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb5: UUID="79e4b0e6-31a2-4ed6-93a5-69d2ac61af43" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb6: UUID="ea51e374-70a2-418f-a015-d7b2d92820c7" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="B44443B344437760" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdc2: LABEL="Windows" UUID="6AE6459BE6456901" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdc3: UUID="8b617ecd-c7a4-4677-b44c-d87233a6602e" TYPE="ext4"
```

`/etc/fstab`:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
UUID=8b617ecd-c7a4-4677-b44c-d87233a6602e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=fc258128-7f32-4bbb-8b14-9c3d3da05619 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
UUID=9017071b-73f2-48af-b205-c1231139a414 /usr/local      ext4    defaults        0       2
```

After the changes, Ubuntu will not boot properly; it sits at a black screen with a blinking underscore.  I tried reinstalling GRUB:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdc3 /mnt
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdc
```

but this did not solve the problem.  For reference, I made all of the changes using GParted from a Live CD boot.  What needs to be done so that Ubuntu will boot once more?

Answer (score 0):

Restore the system to its original condition.

And then move the partitions with the correct procedure.

In a normal session:

You must mount the partition on a temporary directory name to copy files to it the original /home.

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>).  Run it:

You create the temporary directory

```
sudo -i 
mkdir /media/hometemp
```

Mount partition

```
mount /dev/sda6 /media/hometemp
```

To copy:

```
cd /home
cp -ax . /media/hometemp
```

This last line is the only one used to clone, attention "." the end.

Now mount the new /home previous  rename the /home partition and remove the old.

```
cd /
mv /home /home.old
mkdir /home
umount /dev/sda6
mount /dev/sda6 /home
```

Now you have to find the UUID of the partition and edit the /etc/fstab file to mount the partition at startup.

```
blkid /dev/sda6
nano /etc/fstab
```

And you add these lines at the end with that reported blkid UUID.

```
# /dev/sda6 was /home
UUID=fc258128-7f32-4bbb-8b14-9c3d3da05619 /home ext4 defaults 0 2
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

Restarting have everything working exactly the same, but with other partitions.

Once everything is working well, delete the /home.old and /media/hometemp

```
sudo -i
rm /home.old
rm /media/hometemp
```

And now

You must mount the partition on a temporary directory name to copy files to it the original /usr/local.

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>).  Run it:

You create the temporary directory

```
sudo -i 
mkdir /media/usrtemp
```

Mount partition

```
mount /dev/sda5 /media/usrtemp
```

To copy:

```
cd /usr/local
cp -ax . /media/usrtemp
```

This last line is the only one used to clone, attention "." the end.

Now mount the new /usr/local previous  rename the /usr/local partition and remove the old.

```
cd /
mv /usr/local /usr/local.old
mkdir /usr/local
umount /dev/sda5
mount /dev/sda5 /usr/local
```

Now you have to find the UUID of the partition and edit the /etc/fstab file to mount the partition at startup.

```
blkid /dev/sda5
nano /etc/fstab
```

And you add these lines at the end with that reported blkid UUID.

```
# /dev/sda5 was /usr/local
UUID=9017071b-73f2-48af-b205-c1231139a414 /usr/local ext4 defaults 0 2
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

Restarting have everything working exactly the same, but with other partitions.

Once everything is working well, delete the /usr/local.old and /media/usrtemp

```
sudo -i
rm /usr/local.old
rm /media/usrtemp
```

Comment: I don't see how this is any different from what I did, other than performing everything in a normal session as opposed to a Live CD boot.  Can you explain why this will work where my method did not?

Comment: cp -ax . -- This command line is the only one used to clone.